# Fail to logman command

Tags: cmd, performancecounter, perfmon

I tried to run the bellow Logman command from command prompt but it is not getting executed.

I have executed following command :

**logman start BDS -b 6/8/2015 12:30:00[PM]**

Note: I am trying to set data counters of perfmon to start at specific time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of start use update followed by countername, followed by -b and -e

```
logman update BDS -b 6/8/2015 12:30:00[PM] -e 6/8/2015 12:35:00[PM]
```

Answer (score 0):

`logman create` and `logman start` are two different things. Have you tried creating the counter before starting it? I work more in powershell, so I'm not sure of the precise syntax you need, but you basically need a command to create the DataCollectorSet, and then one to start it. So, something like:

```
logman create BDS [your counters here] [begin/end paramters here]
logman start BDS
```